# Geofence and GPS-Tracking in QGIS

Tags: qgis, tracking, geofencing

What is the easiest possibility to create a geofence and to track if subjects  cross the fence?

I assume the fence is a simple polygon vector?

What do I need for the cars? GPS data set? GPS layer?